# symfony: how to use a validator class existing in a different folder

Tags: symfony

Seems to me that Symfony try to find validator classes by **default** in this folder:

```
/mybundle
     | /validator
           | -EmailNotUsedValidator.php
```

The validations is done by this class "EmailNotUsed.php"

```
class EmailNotUsed extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This email is already being used';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'EmailNotUsedValidator';
    }
}
```

But I want to use a different folder:

```
/mybundle
     | /Forms
         |/Validators
              | -EmailNotUsedValidator.php
```

How can I make this change?, **is trying to find the validator all the time in the default folder, however I want to use the other one**

Comment: just a guess: return 'mybundle:Forms:Validators:EmailNotUsedValidator'

Comment: well, good idea, is not working but is a good idea. thanks

Comment: ou, is working. In the end I wrote mybundle\Forms\Validators\EmailNotUsedValidator. Thanks friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the docs

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies

you can register the validator as a service and give it an alias (similarly to form types)
and use its aliast in validatedBy()